Spring Boot 3: Jetty Mgmt Server allows TRACE method calls
I made a Spring Boot 3 application with spring-boot-starter-jetty and actuator where server.port != management.server.port.
I want TRACE calls to not be allowed both on the server and mgmt port.
I tried several approaches but I managed to have TRACE blocked only for the server port while the server on mgmt port always accepts TRACE calls with 200 OK.
Follow up on this Spring Boot issue ref
I made the following test application to show what I see
Test testTraceDisabledManagement won't pass
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── com
│   │   │       └── example
│   │   │           ├── demo
│   │   │           │   ├── CustomDispatcherServlet.java
│   │   │           │   └── DemoApplication.java
│   │   │           └── server
│   │   │               └── MgmtServerConfiguration.java
│   │   └── resources
│   │       ├── META-INF
│   │       │   └── spring
│   │       │       └── org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.ManagementContextConfiguration.imports
│   │       ├── application.properties
│   │       ├── static
│   │       └── templates
│   └── test
│       └── java
│           └── com
│               └── example
│                   └── demo
│                       └── DemoApplicationTests.java

Test
@Test
    public void testTraceDisabledApi() throws URISyntaxException {
        verifyTraceFails(this.apiPort); // OK - Jetty returns 405
    }

    /**
     * Tests that TRACE is disabled for the management endpoint.
     */
    @Test
    public void testTraceDisabledManagement() throws URISyntaxException {
        verifyTraceFails(this.managementPort); // KO - Jetty returns 200
    }

    private void verifyTraceFails(final int port) throws URISyntaxException {
        final String url = "http://localhost:" + port;
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        try {
            RequestEntity<Void> requestEntity = new RequestEntity<>(TRACE, new URI(url));
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, String.class);
            assertThat(response.getStatusCode(), Matchers.equalTo(METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED));
        }
        catch (org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException e) {
            assertThat(e.getStatusCode(), Matchers.equalTo(METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED));
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Assertions.fail("Should never reach this point", e);
        }
        Assertions.fail("Should never reach this point");
    }

Project structure

I figured out what the issue was. I was using JettyServerCustomizer class to configure Jetty, but it seems to be ignored by the management server.
While WebServerFactoryCustomizer did the trick.
The project in the main post is updated and tests are passing in case.
-    JettyServerCustomizer mgmtJettyServerCustomizer() {
-        return (server) -> {
-            ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = findServletContextHandler(server);
-            disableTraceMethodForHandler(servletContextHandler);
+    WebServerFactoryCustomizer<JettyServletWebServerFactory> disableTrace() {
+        return (factory) -> {
+            factory.addServerCustomizers((server) -> {
+                ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = findServletContextHandler(server);
+                disableTraceMethodForHandler(servletContextHandler);
+            });

